# Shimano Claris and Sora left brifters interchangeable?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter, drop-bar, brifters

Are the left brifters for Sora ST-R3000 and Claris ST-R2000 interchangeable, assuming they're both 2x? The pull ratio should be the same since they're made for x9 and x8 drivetrains, respectively, right?

Assuming the ratios are the same, do they look and *feel* the same? Or are they engineered to a noticeably different shape?

(I'm asking because I currently have 2x9 MicroNew brifters that I *hate*, and I want to replace them with Sora, but since it's mainly for aesthetics, I can't justify spending a lot of cash on it. I was thinking of doing a Sora rear shifter and a 2x Claris front shifter. But even if the Claris pulls the FD just fine, would it feel weird in my hands to have mismatched shifters?)

Comment: in my area, they are only available new as a matched pair so the question raises a moot point. the difference in cost is minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are very likely compatible with each other, although it is not stated in the compatibility chart and should be verified.

No, the pull ratio is not the same as the traditional one. It has changed with the R-2000 and R-3000 series and hence is not the same as the older Claris and older Sora like ST-3500 or ST-2400. For compatibility with Microshift you likely need some older Shimano model.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even consider the MicroNew 2x9 old differ from modern Shimano 2x9 (and as a side note, MicroNew is a different—and inferior—brand from MicroShift). Do you know what it that old ratio is? I wonder if there's any brifters *with integrated shift cables* that would be compatible...

Comment: From what It in reading, it looks like it's only the FD that changed from short to long pull, actually. I literally just bought a short pull FD but I guess I could buy a long pull one. Probably the cheapest part of the groupset to replace anyway

Comment: Going back to the last part of the question, do you know whether Sora and Claris would feel noticeably different in the hand?

Comment: I own both of them, but the bikes are most often at a different location. But they are very similar. I think the shape is identical, but I never tried to hold each in one hand..

Comment: UPDATE: I have installed Sora R3000 brifters with the old 105 front derailleur (FD-5501), and while the cable pulls for each component are intended to be different, functionally they are perfectly compatible. The new lever can shift the old derailleur just fine.